# Can we use the crypto module in react native for making the public and private key pair like in NodeJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have used various modules in react native but I am getting errors, I have windows 10. How I can setup perfectly the crypto module setup in react-native.

the module i have used is:

**react-native-crypto**

I need to create public and private key pair and encrypt the data with the public key of the users between for sharing messages.

Comment: What is the error message? How did your code look like?

Comment: I am getting 2 errors 1 is "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNRandomBytes.seed')" and 2nd is "Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called."